# Class not showing view from NIB

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, nib

When I call my view controller, it comes up blank and does not seem to be correctly calling the layout in my NIB. I have at least 5 other classes that respect my NIB layout just fine.

I have a class `chwFinishedViewController.h`

On my storyboard I have a `UIViewController` that is assigned this class and given the storyboardID `complete`. See the below screenshot

[image: issue screenshot]

Here is `chwFinishedViewController.m`

```
#import "chwFinishedViewController.h"

@interface chwFinishedViewController ()

@end

@implementation chwFinishedViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here is how I call the controller. Everything before the controller call execute properly:

```
 if (!error) {
chwFinishedViewController *complete = [[chwFinishedViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:complete animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: I've edited my post for storyboard

Comment: And I have a little criticism to your code. If method contains only call of this method by `super` class, you may want to remove this method at all. For example, `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
chwFinishedViewController *complete = [[chwFinishedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"complete" bundle:nil];
```

There is no relation between your xib and chwFinishedViewController constructor. You use just `init` which doesn't make anything. [Here's apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a).

**EDIT**

You use storyboard. So try this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
chwFinishedViewController* complete = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"complete"];
```

Comment: It returns: " No visible @interface for 'chwFinishedViewController' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:' "

Comment: @user3085646, sorry, use `initWithNibName:bundle:` instead.

Comment: Your storyboard edit works. I started with something similar, but I was using `chwFinishedViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"complete"];` but that kicked a completely different error out. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
 you have just init the controller..
use initWithNibName instead of only init
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
chwFinishedViewController *complete = [[chwFinishedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"complete" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Hmmm. That gives me: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/.../Chewsey.app> (loaded)' with name 'complete''

Comment: my storyboard is named "Main" but the UIViewController on the main.storyboard has a storyboardID "complete". Is it because I'm using initWithNibName:[storyboardID] and not the name of the NIB file?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
chwFinishedViewController *complete = [[chwFinishedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"complete" bundle:nil];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my solution was to remove an empty loadView method that had gotten left behind in the code for the viewcontroller class.